# JMETER JTL Log File Sizes

Tags: jmeter

I am running jmeter through the command line, and generating a jtl log file. The last couple of runs, it seems that it has created a couple of different .jtl files, with one of them starting in the middle of the run. Is there a Maximum Length of a Log File, or has anyone seen anything like this before?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The JTL files can grow as large as they need to be.  In some cases my tests yield JTL files over 25 gigs in size.

However, if you do not change the JTL name between runs it will append to the file, not overwrite.  Is it possible you are looking at two test runs in a single JTL file?  You would see a big chunk where it looks like there are no results.

If you are running from command line, my suggestion would be to build a shell or batch script that auto timestamps the jtl parameter and starts the test.  This way you are guaranteed, without any thinking, to have new files for each run.

Also, just so you are aware:  There is a nice plugin jar that will allow you to generate awesome graphs from a raw JTL file!
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, after I did some additional research, I figured out that my problem was related to the fact that someone had tried doing some work and left a different file file name in one of the report listeners, which was what I mistakenly thinking that I had multiple files being written to.  As for using the JMETERPluginsCMD Tool, is there any advantage to this over just doing this through the GUI.